# How to return data in object format for web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I have to return data in json format but it says cannot implicitly convert type string to system.collection.generic.list(object).

```
 [HttpGet]
    public List<object> GetAllCompanies2()
    {
        List<object> myCo = DefCompany.AllDefCompany2;
         // return myCo----------> works

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCo);
        return  json; ------- > not works conversion error & i need this
    }
```

I tried tostring() and many other ways but nothing worked. How can I convert string to object?
Here is my function code AllDefCompany2

```
   public static List<object> AllDefCompany2
    {
        get
        {
            using (var db = new RPDBEntities())
            {

                return db.DefCompanies.Select(b => new 
                {
                    Id = b.Id,

                    CurrentCurrencyCode = b.CurrentCurrencyCode,
                    ShortName = b.ShortName,
                    FullName = b.FullName,
                    ContactPerson = b.ContactPerson,
                    Address1 = b.Address1,
                    CompanyCity = b.CompanyCity,
                    CompanyState = b.CompanyState,
                    CompanyCountry = b.CompanyCountry,
                    ZipPostCode = b.ZipPostCode,
                    TelArea = b.TelArea

                }).ToList<object>();


            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCo)` doesn't return the data in a `json` format, rather as a `string` that can be later parsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code helps me to solve both api and kendo problem

```
[HttpGet]
public List<object> GetAllCompanies2()
{
    List<object> myCo = DefCompany.AllDefCompany2;         

    object json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCo);
    return  json;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is configuration settings

```
 using System.Data.Entity;

  namespace RpManticSolAPI
  {
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);          
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCo);
```

Comment: Just code is not enough, explain what you are doing here

Comment: Assuming the object myCo returns is the List. The error is because you are returning a STRING variable. (`return json`) whereas the method is expecting a return type of `List<object>`

Comment: the return value of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCo)` is still a `string`, it won't make a difference if you don't store it in a variable first

Comment: i have to call api and populate grid , grid sucessfully populated but api during testing says: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `string` to `object`, but what you are trying to do in the code shown is convert it to a `List<object>`. You can try calling `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` on the `json` variable.

But if what you want to do is return a string, why not change the return type of the method?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetAllCompanies2()
{
    List<object> myCo = DefCompany.AllDefCompany2;
     // return myCo----------> works

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCo);
    return  json; ------- > not works conversion error & i need this
}
```

Try this. Need to change function return type based on whether you return list of objects or string (in this case json)

Comment: i have to populate kendo grid even in this way my kendo grid does not populate